# Where to put initialisation code (in Mioguel Grinberg's Flasky app)

Tags: flask

I am building an app using Miguel's Flasky code as the basic framework to start with. I'm following his structure but with separate Blueprints for each major discrete part of my own additional functionality.

During any initial deployment, I need the app to initialise the database with a system user, various system-related defaults, etc.

Where in the Flasky app should I put the code to do this? It obviously has to be invoked before any user interactions but will need to reference app, db and SQLAlchemy models defined in several of the Bluprints, so must be after these have all been imported.

I'm thinking it should be in a function in the app __init__.py which I then call at the end of the app.create_app function, after all the blueprint imports. It would obviously test for whether initialisation has already happened (i.e. is this a first run, not just a restart of the app).

Is that where people usually put first-time initialisation code?

Comment: If you look at the source code on github, you will see that Miguel defines a cli deploy() function in 'flasky.py'. [see here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/flasky.py)

Comment: Yes saw that, but it's a cli function requiring an admin at the terminal. Also, wouldn't it have to register all the plugins and blueprints before it could do what I need? I'm looking for somewhere to put initialisation code in the app itself, after everything has been registered/imported, but before it starts serving users.